# How can get instance from singleton class with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Consider this code:

```
public class Test
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Test> Lazy = new Lazy<Test>(() => new Test());

    private Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calling constractor");
    }

    public static Test Instance
    {
        get { return Lazy.Value; }
    }

    public void Something()
    {
    }
}
```

When i want to create instance from above class we should change the constructor's access modifier to  public and for get instance from this class i write this code:

```
  Type type = typeof(Test);
        IEnumerable<Type> types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList()
                                           .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                                           .Where(type.IsAssignableFrom);
        Type strtegy = types.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsClass);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Activator.CreateInstance(strtegy);
        }
```

If use this code,for each time that call  `Activator.CreateInstance` constructor should call.So we have many instance of the class.

How can  get instance from singleton class with reflection ?

Comment: Get the value of the `Instance` property...

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Whatt?

Comment: Are you asking how to retrieve the `Instance` via reflection? Or are you trying to bypass the Singleton and instantiate a brand new instance? Your question isn't clear on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To create an instance, do the same thing you would do in code -- get the value of `Instance`:

```
var singleton = typeof(Test).GetProperty("Instance").GetValue(null);
```

Comment: This is what I assumed the OP meant.. but I wasn't sure. +1 anyway

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the appropriate flags to GetProperty() to make this work:

```
var property = strtegy.GetProperty("Instance", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
var instance = property.GetValue(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use the constructor, just get access to the property.

```
var value = typeof (Test).GetProperty("Instance").GetValue(null, null);
```